# Sketch: How to change all shades of a color to another color?

Tags: sketch-app, color-conversion

I have an image that I downloaded online:
[image]

As you can see it's not just monotone. I would like to change all shades of the red to shades of a different color (Imagine the red liquid was purple instead of red)

Is this possible in Sketch?

Sorry I'm a programmer, so this is kinda outta my realm of expertise. I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch has a 'colour adjust' facility that should do exactly what you are trying to achieve here. To change the colour of the liquid in your image to a different colour in the  way that you describe, you should only need to adjust the 'hue' slider, but it will be worth having a play with the other sliders too in order to tweak the result to your liking.

I found a site with more details here : http://www.sketchtips.info/articles/color-adjust

Comment: wow this is exactly what i wanted!!!! thanks so much

Comment: unrelated but would you know how to change the white background to a different color?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that outside of Sketch.
Sketch is not good at pixel minipulation. It provides a basic set of tweaks, but not this one.